# How can I properly use Catch[] to prevent my program from quitting?

Tags: hold, debugging, error-tracking, error-trapping

I am getting an error depicting an Uncaught Throw, with the accompanying code being returned:

```
Hold[Throw[$Failed, CURLLink`Utilities`Exception]]
```

I have managed to track down the function where the error is coming from by logging the part of code being run when the program fails, and am now attempting to use `Catch[]` to resolve the error. However, the error persists despite me wrapping `Catch[]` around the portion of code that I believe is responsible. Is there a limit to what can fit inside of `Catch[]`?

As far as my understanding of `Catch[]` goes, I thought that it would automatically grab any error messages being returned and prevent the program from quitting. Is my basic assumption about this function incorrect?

I have done a lot of research in my free time over the last few weeks to try and fix this bug, including looking over posts on this site, but understanding error correction properly has alluded me. I appreciate the help.

Here is a screenshot of the code, which pulls certain emails from my account:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using a single-arg [`Catch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch). Single-arg [`Catch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch) will not catch a multi-arg [`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw). Compare:

```
Catch[Throw[1, "FOO"]]
```

Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[1,FOO] returned to top level.

> Hold[Throw[1, "FOO"]]

with:

```
Catch[Throw[1, "FOO"], "FOO"]
```

> 1

Perhaps that's all that's wrong?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was not aware there could be multiple arguments to a Throw[] - I will try that out and let it run to see if it fixes the problem!

Comment: It seems to be working, thanks!

Comment: Just for completeness: a catch-all version would be `Catch[code,_]`. This would help even if a `Throw` with any other tag would be evaluated...